# Linking to a question worsening Google result

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I moved this information from the Ubuntu wiki to AU:

- [What are Unity's keyboard and mouse shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28086/keyboard-shortcuts-in-unity)

Within 10 minutes of posting it it was the #3 hit on Google for "unity keyboard shortcuts". Somebody noticed and [ran a story](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCAQqQIwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownloadsquad.switched.com%2F2011%2F02%2F26%2Fubuntu-11-04-unity-keyboard-shortcuts-have-a-distinct-windows-7%2F&ei=tvxpTbG7JMiDtge-1vTmAg&usg=AFQjCNE7PR04MMvGwH97wbEKmkI5aY58OQ) and it was also picked up by [webupd8](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&sqi=2&ved=0CEYQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.webupd8.org%2F2011%2F02%2Funity-ubuntu-1104-keyboard-shortcuts.html&ei=tvxpTbG7JMiDtge-1vTmAg&usg=AFQjCNHrTfXsvCIcFn89hEFhvLHkZanYIw), which runs Ubuntu-related news stories.

As of this post the original question is now on page 7! Content-farmed duplicates of the original story litter the pages, as well as other legitimately related unity bits. Adding 11.04, ubuntu, or other related terms doesn't seem to work, except ... putting 11.04 as the *first* search term finally gets the original content on the front page as the 10th result.

This isn't really a question as much as it's feedback to the SO folks if they need data for improving search results. I moved the content here because I was sick of never being able to find the page buried in the wiki, so I was elated when it was indexed so quickly, but alas, smoked by content farms.

Comment: Just to say, for me then the AU result is #3 (#4 if you count the Google News link at the top) with webup8 at #6 and download squad at #7.

Comment: For me search in quotes is #3, search without quotes #2. Maybe a local thing. See also answers to [my question on search results](http://askubuntu.com/questions/9663/why-does-google-search-always-count-more-results-in-firefox-or-chrome-than-in-chr)

Comment: I also see the page at position #4 without quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems OK if you put it in quotes

http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=%22keyboard+shortcuts+in+unity%22

I think this got a lot of publicity which may have skewed the results

http://downloadsquad.switched.com/2011/02/26/ubuntu-11-04-unity-keyboard-shortcuts-have-a-distinct-windows-7/

Comment: Ah it seems to have worked itself out, it's showing up right in the middle of the front page now.

Comment: It is first with quotes, but does anyone even uses quotes or any kind of Google special operator? It is third without which isn't too bad, we really aren't out there to advertise per se. When I Google stuff I normally select AU (or anyone SE) over other results.